# Child component does not rerender when parent changes prop

Tags: reactjs, render, web-component, use-effect, use-state

The parent component:

```
const Parent =
...
var render = {};
render.value = false;
...

return (
<div>
  <button onClick= { () => {render.value = ! render.value; console.log(render);} } >Change Prop</button>
</div>
<Child render = { render } />
...
)
```

The child component:

```
const Child = ({render}) => {
  
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('This does not show up when i click parents button');
    }, [render]);

return (<div></div>)
```

Shouldn't the child re render due to prop change ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think you are updating `render` value correctly. try this:

```
const Parent = () => {
   const [render, setRender] = useState({})

  return (
     <div>
       <button onClick={() => setRender({...render, value: false})} >Change 
         Prop
       </button>
       <Child render={render} />
     </div>
  )
}
```

that is setting the state of the parent to a new value, which in turn will pass it as a prop to `child` and trigger a render in the child component

remember to use `state` in React components for values that will change and need passing down as props. only reason to not use `state` is for constant values that do not change